# How to access instance by two different types when using dependency injection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, .net-core

I have the following class:

```
public class CustomDatabase : DbContext
{
    public void Function1(){..}
}

public class CustomerDb : CustomDatabase 
{
    public void GetCustomerById(guid id){..}
}
```

This is created by calling

```
services.AddDbContext<CustomerDb>();
```

and is used all around the code as `CustomerDb`.

I now want to use a middleware from a nuget that does not know about my project, but knows about the `CustomDatabase` implementation. But when I try to refer to `CustomDatabase` I get an run-time error saying that the DI framework can not find `CustomDatabase`.

How can I make it so I can refer to this instance as both `CustomDatabase` and `CustomerDb`?

Comment: Is your middelware project has the reference dll of CustomDatabase ?

Comment: You can call `AddDbContext` more than once, so you can register both CustomDatabase and CustomerDb. Where you say, "knows about the CustomDatabase implementation," do you mean that it expects to have CustomDatabase injected?

Comment: My middleware project has a reference to the dll of CustomDatabase

Comment: If I add the context twice, do I not get two objects? I need it to point to the same instance

Comment: "I need it to point to the same instance" - DbContext instances are normally transient, unless you have a really good and well-defined reason to keep one around long enough to make sharing across modules a valid concern.

Comment: If all `CustomerDb` does is add methods to `CustomDatabase`, it might make more sense to make it into a static class and rewrite it's methods as extension methods (i.e. `GetCustomerById(this CustomDatabase database, guid id){..}`.

Comment: CustomDatabase has a set of variables. Basically it keeps track of if the context has been saved or has unsaved changes. The middleware then checks if there are changes and depending on other parts of the code throws an error. Its a way of catching issues related to tracking in a legacy project.

So the middleware needs to access the same instance, but as we have multiple databases, it does not know or need to know what the actual implementation is, as long as it is a CustomDatabase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register the context as you have done originally and also include a registration for the derived type using the same lifetime with the factory delegate

```
services.AddDbContext<CustomerDb>();
services.AddScoped<CustomDatabase>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<CustomerDb>());
```

Comment: This is the solution I ended up with.

Comment: I don't think it a good practice, because an instance of CustomerDb would be disposed for twice. And additionally, We should not use a factory delegate with  `GetRequiredService` to wrap another service because it converts a null condition to an exception, so that if it fails to resolve `CustomerDb`, a simple call to `GetService<CustomDatabase>()` would throw an exception instead of returning null which is an unexpected behavior, since `GetService` is expected to return null on fails.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot achieve this with the default DI container (aka. `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`) because it does not support registering a service as multiple resolving interfaces. Even if you register one type as factory function that resolves and return another one, the service would be duplicately disposed (This could even be a possible solution if the service implementation type does not implement `IDisposable` or its `Dispose` method could be called for multiple times without unexpected behaviors). eg.

Given the types:

```
interface I1 { }

interface I2 { }

class C : I1, I2 { }
```

If the service implementation type does not implement `IDisposable` or its `Dispose` method could be called for multiple times without unexpected behaviors:

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddSingleton<I1, C>();
services.AddSingleton<I2>(p => (I2)p.GetService<I1>());  //Must be exactly the same lifetime scope
var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var i1 = provider.GetRequiredService<I1>();
var i2 = provider.GetRequiredService<I2>();
Console.WriteLine(i1 == i2);  //True
```

But you can use [Autofac](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html) to replace the default service provider that can easily do it.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<C>().AsImplementedInterfaces().SingleInstance();
var container = builder.Build();
var i1 = container.Resolve<I1>();
var i2 = container.Resolve<I2>();
Console.WriteLine(i1 == i2);  //true
```

As for your `DbContext` classes, you could register it manually:

```
builder
    .RegisterType<CustomerDb>()
    .AsSelf()  //So that it could be resolved as CustomerDb
    .As<CustomDatabase>()  //So that it could be resolved as CustomDatabase
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope()  //Note that EF Core's DbContext is designed to be scoped services
    .OwnedByLifetimeScope();  //Dispose when the scope (the request lifetime) is disposed as the default service provider does
```